# jQuery how to pass in more than 1 parameters in the load method

Tags: jquery, load

I have a load method loading some data. But its not liking how i am loading more than 1 parameter. Is there a way to load more than 1 parameter. Also I want to be able to get the selected index and place it where the 0 is with jquery(this).attr("selectedIndex")) is that possible. Here is my code.

```
   jQuery('#EntryForm').load('../IRElectricalBaselineEntryPage.aspx #contentBlockElectrical',
                { trainid: <%=Inspections[0].ID%> , inspectid: <%=Equipment.ID%> });
```

where that Inspections[0] I want to place jquery(this).attr("selectedIndex"))

Thanks!

Comment: In `jQuery(this).attr("selectedIndex")`, what does `this` refer to?

Comment: That grabs the selected index from the select element. So if they chose the 2nd item the selectedindex would be 1. its 0 based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ trainid: <%=Inspections[0].ID%> , inspectid: <%=Equipment.ID%> }
```

This should work fine, but you may need to but the values in quotes.

```
{ trainid: '<%=Inspections[0].ID%>' , inspectid: '<%=Equipment.ID%>' }
```

If you want to use `jQuery(this).attr("selectedIndex")`, to get a value from `Inspections`, you'll need to save `<%=Inspections%>` to a JavaScript array first, then get the element you want.  I don't know ASP, so I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options...
1.  You can use the querystring like this...

```
$("#myDiv").load("PageName.aspx?myVarA=" + myVarAVal + "&myVarB=" + myVarBVal);
```

1. Or you can pass in arrays of data - remember that this command is truly just shorthand for $.ajax ...

$("#myDiv").load("PageName.aspx", {myVarA : myVarAVal});

Answer (score -1):

```
../IRElectricalBaselineEntryPage.aspx #contentBlockElectrical
```

Take the anchor ("#contentBlockElectrical") off and that should work. Looks like you're confusing it about the URL where you want it to post the information.

Comment: The `#contentBlockElectrical` part tells jQuery to only load that part of the page.